# Java объединение видеофайлов в один FFmpeg

Tags: java, видео, ffmpeg, javacv

Код:

```
for (File f : files) {
            FrameGrabber grabber = new FFmpegFrameGrabber(f.getPath());
            grabber.start();
            while ((frame = grabber.grab()) != null) {
                recorder.record(frame);
            }
            grabber.stop();
        }
```

И вроде работает нормально, но если файлов много, то долго очень. Есть какой-нибудь метод у этой библиотеки, чтобы просто склеить файлы, а не "грабить" каждый?

Comment: Не готов давать полноценный ответ, но смотрите такой расклад: я не знаю какой у вас контейнер, но, в общем случае, нужно, как минимум скорректировать PTS./DTS у каждого фрейма, начиная со второго файла. Т.е. обрабатывать ПОФРЕЙМОВО нужно, от этого никуда не уйдёшь. НО: если делается только склейка и видео в одинаковом формате (кодек, параметры кодирования, разрешение, фреймрейт и т.п.), то можно исключить ДЕКОДИРОВАНИЕ и КОДИРОВАНИЕ. Т.е. вы осущиствите трансмуксинг. Чисто средствами FFmpeg (libavformat) это делается достаточно просто. В обёртке JavaCV - нужно смотреть документацию.

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите в сторону FfmpegController.concatAndTrimFilesMP4Stream():

```
package org.ffmpeg.android.test;


import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Locale;

import net.sourceforge.sox.SoxController;

import org.ffmpeg.android.Clip;
import org.ffmpeg.android.FfmpegController;
import org.ffmpeg.android.ShellUtils;

public class ConcatTest {

    public static void test (String videoRoot, String fileTmpPath, String fileOut, double fadeLen) throws Exception
    {
        File fileTmp = new File(fileTmpPath);
        File fileAppRoot = new File("");
        File fileVideoRoot = new File(videoRoot);

        FfmpegController fc = new FfmpegController(null, fileTmp);
         SoxController sxCon = new SoxController(null, fileAppRoot, null);

        ArrayList<Clip> listVideos = new ArrayList<Clip>();

        String[] fileList = fileVideoRoot.list();
        for (String fileVideo : fileList)
        {
            if (fileVideo.endsWith("mp4"))
            {
                Clip clip = new Clip();
                clip.path = new File(fileVideoRoot,fileVideo).getCanonicalPath();

                fc.getInfo(clip);

                clip.duration = clip.duration-fadeLen;
                listVideos.add(clip);


            }
        }

        Clip clipOut = new Clip ();
        clipOut.path = new File(fileOut).getCanonicalPath();

        fc.concatAndTrimFilesMP4Stream(listVideos, clipOut, false, false, new ShellUtils.ShellCallback() {

            @Override
            public void shellOut(String shellLine) {

                System.out.println("fc>" + shellLine);
            }

            @Override
            public void processComplete(int exitValue) {

                if (exitValue < 0)
                    System.err.println("concat non-zero exit: " + exitValue);
            }
        });



    }
}
```

Взято [отсюда](https://github.com/guardianproject/android-ffmpeg-java/blob/master/src/org/ffmpeg/android/test/ConcatTest.java)

Answer (score 0):

Возможно это вам поможет:

```
cmd="( "

    h264options="-vcodec libx264 -b 512k -flags +loop+mv4 -cmp 256 \
     -partitions +parti4x4+parti8x8+partp4x4+partp8x8+partb8x8 \
     -me_method hex -subq 7 -trellis 1 -refs 5 -bf 3 \
     -flags2 +bpyramid+wpred+mixed_refs+dct8x8 -coder 1 -me_range 16 \
       -g 250 -keyint_min 25 -sc_threshold 40 -i_qfactor 0.71 -qmin 10\
     -qmax 51 -qdiff 4"

    outfile="out-`date +%F-%H%M.%S`.mp4"

    for i; do
        cmd="${cmd}ffmpeg -i $i -ab 256000 -vb 10000000 -mbd rd -trellis 2 -cmp 2 -subcmp 2 -g 100 -f mpeg -; "
    done
    cmd="${cmd} ) | ffmpeg -y -i - -threads 8 ${h264options} -vb 10000000 -acodec libfaac -ar 44100 -ab 128k -s 1280x720 ${outfile}"
    echo "${cmd}"
    eval ${cmd}
```